# Static_cast and templated conversion function

Tags: c++, type-conversion, sfinae

I have a class that wraps some type and attaches a Dimension. It should be convertible to the underlying type, but only if `Dim=0`. The conversion operator should not be callable in other cases (so a `static_assert` in the function would not work for me).

The following code works, if the `enable_if`-construction is deleted, but not in this form.

```
template<class T, int Dim>
class Unit {
    public:
    explicit Unit(T const& value): _value(value) {}

    template<int D = Dim, typename = typename std::enable_if<D == 0>::type>
    operator T() { return _value; }
    private:
    T _value;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    auto a = double{0};
    auto u = Unit<double, 0>{a};
    auto i = static_cast<int>(u);    
    return i;
}
```

What is the reason for this and is there a work around to allow the cast, but also restrict the conversion?

Comment: _It should be convertible to the underlying type_, but you are constructing `u` from a `double` and trying to cast it to `int`, which is not the "underlying type", I guess. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want:

```
template <class T, int Dim>
class Unit {
public:
    explicit Unit(T const& value): _value(value) {}

    template <typename U, int D = Dim,
              std::enable_if_t<D == 0 && std::is_convertible_v<T, U>, int> = 0>
    operator U() { return _value; }
private:
    T _value;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6cKj1W3EM)

And in C++20, look nicer

```
template<class T, int Dim>
class Unit {
    public:
    explicit Unit(T const& value): _value(value) {}

    template <typename U>
    requires(Dim == 0 && std::is_convertible_v<T, U>)
    operator U() const { return _value; }
private:
    T _value;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KaPxs3PnM)

Comment: This should then probably be overloaded with the conversion to `T` to have the best default choice, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, in the above example, `operator int()` is created, not `static_cast<int>(static_cast<double>(u))`...